# How can I get time from SEC_TO_TIME in MySQL and disregard the seconds on the format?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, time

I have a query wherein I'm getting the sum of the recorded time for overtime of an employee.

Supposing that I have two overtime records for Employee A.

```
Name          Overtime
Employee A    00:30
Employee A    00:45
```

On my initial select query, I can sum Employee A's overtime but I'm getting a result like this

```
01:30:00
```

How can I just display the number of hours and minutes of the sum time (`01:30`) and disregard the seconds? By the way, kindly take a look on the select column in my query below.

```
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(  `basic_ot` ) ) )
```

Comment: `but I'm getting a result like this` I don't see how you could end up with that sum for Employee A.

Comment: What is the type of the `Overtime` column?

Comment: Hi, I used a varchar for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`TIME_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format):

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('12:30:30', '%H %s') FROM dual;
                                ^^ ^^ hours in 24 format, seconds
```

**Output:**

```
12 30
```

## Demo

Comment: @user3819290 Glad to help.  I was able to guess what you wanted, but in the future, try to make your questions as clear as possible, and show examples with actual data.